make: msp430-gcc:command not found in Cooja
I encountered an error when running a simulation in Cooja.
Initially, I created a new simulation and added a Skymote, and it worked very well and I run 3 new simulation . However, when I attempted to create another simulation, I faced this error [ make: msp430-gcc:command not found] , even though it was working fine in the first simulation.
I tried to delete VMware  and reinstall every thing
also I checked the version of MSP430, and it is (v4.7.3).
I use Contiki 2.7  and VMware Workstation 17 Player
please I need further assistance
i need some advice to fix the error
